# l3regex - Line by line splitting

Tags: l3regex

I'd like to analyse the contents of an environment line by line, but the following minimalistic testing code fails by "printing" `false`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{linebyline}{b}{
    \seq_new:N \l_temp_seq
    \regex_split:nnNTF { \n } { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq
        { true }
        { false }
}{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{linebyline}
% Comment
    Line 1
    Line 2
% Comment
    Line 3
\end{linebyline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: end of line is tokenized as a space by default

Comment: Gosh... I wanted to avoid using `\\\` for line breaks.

Comment: tex is tex..., you need `\obeylines` or set `\endlinechar` or ...

Comment: I will investigate this. Thanks for showing me the light... :-)

Comment: And don't use `regex` for this. Splitting at a single character can be done with `\seq_set_split:Nnn` or `\seq_set_split_keep_spaces:Nnn`.

Comment: @Skillmon You are right, but this is just a toy example...

Comment: @projetmbc still shows a tool too complicated and wasteful for the job... Your request never needed `regex` if it's just about splitting lines, and I wanted to make sure you realise this. `l3regex` is brilliant code, don't get me wrong, but it is used "in the wild" way too often for things simpler tools can do just as well yet hundreds of times faster.

Comment: Due to a precise design choice of TeX, how the input is split across lines is completely irrelevant, so long as line breaks correspond to spaces in output. So it's essentially meaningless to “analyze the input line-by-line”.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with a command rather than an environment, **which is not my need**, and using regular expressions instead of `seq_set_split:Nnn` or `seq_set_split_keep_spaces:Nnn`.

---

***Any advice to a split-seq solution is welcome.***

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\linebyline}{+v}{
    \seq_new:N \l_temp_seq
    \regex_split:nnN {\^^M} {#1} \l_tmpa_seq 
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { :: }
}{}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\linebyline{
% Comment
    Line 1
    Line 2
% Comment
    Line 3
}

\end{document}
```

This code outputs:

```
::% Comment::Line 1::Line 2::% Comment::Line 3::
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you are looking for, but with `\obeylines` in place within the environment, a token cycle can be used to search for the line ends and emplace (as in your example) a `::` between lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
{\obeylines
\gdef\mycr{
}}
\def\myenvname{linebyline}
\newenvironment{\myenvname}{\obeylines\catcode`\%=12 \tokencycle
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {%
  \expandafter\ifx\mycr##1\addcytoks{::}\else
    \ifx\end##1
      \tcpop\z\tcpushgroup\z%
      \ifx\z\myenvname
        \tcpush{\noexpand\endtokcycraw##1}%
      \else\addcytoks{##1}\fi
    \else\addcytoks{##1}\fi
  \fi}
 {\addcytoks{##1}}}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{linebyline}
% Comment
    Line 1
    Line 2
% Comment
    Line 3
\end{linebyline}

Back to
normal
text.

\begin{linebyline}
% Comment
    Line 1 \today
    Line 2\begin{itemize} \item xxx\end{itemize}
% Comment
    Line 3
\end{linebyline}

Back to % absolutely
normal
text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one desires the parsed content to *not* be executed, but instead detokenized, and the line content of each line collected, one can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
{\obeylines
\gdef\mycr{
}}
\def\myenvname{linebyline}
\newenvironment{\myenvname}{\obeylines\catcode`\%=12 \tokencycle
  {\addcytoks{\string##1}}
  {\addcytoks{\{}\processtoks{##1}\addcytoks{\}}}
  {%
  \expandafter\ifx\mycr##1
    \mbox{}\\Input line: ``\the\cytoks''% <-CURRENT INPUT LINE
    \cytoks{}%
  \else
    \ifx\end##1
      \tcpop\z\tcpushgroup\z%
      \ifx\z\myenvname
        \tcpush{\noexpand\endtokcycraw##1}%
      \else\addcytoks{\detokenize{##1}}\fi
    \else\addcytoks{\detokenize{##1}}\fi
  \fi}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{linebyline}
% Comment
    Line 1
    Line 2
% Comment
    Line 3
\end{linebyline}

Back to
normal
text.

\begin{linebyline}
% Comment
    Line 1 \today
    Line 2\begin{itemize} \item xxx\end{itemize}
% Comment
    Line 3
\end{linebyline}

Back to % absolutely
normal
text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this proposition. Concretely, I want to use a DSL (Domain Specific Language) to type easily tables of variation and/or signs of real functions. In my partial answer, the `l3` sequence will serve to analyse each line of the DSL.

Comment: @projetmbc In my implementation, the code of each line is actually executed (as in the `itemize`).  However, I could just as easily have `\string`ed the output, making it more verbatim-like, if that were preferable.

Comment: @projetmbc See my edit.